# Slot in module xml in Jboss AS 7

Tags: jboss7.x

In module.xml file in Jboss AS 7, I have a dependency

```
<dependencies> 
     <module name="org.apache.camel.components" slot="company"/>
</dependencies>
```

I dont know what does the slot refers in the dependency module.

Kindly guide me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `slot` attribute is for specifying the version of the module you want to include, it defaults to `main` when not specified.

For reference, see

- [Module Descriptor](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Module+descriptors) on the jboss Modules wiki
- [module-1_1.xsd](https://raw.github.com/jbossas/jboss-modules/1.1.3.GA/src/main/resources/schema/module-1_1.xsd) on GitHub